# iOS: How to have the container view automatically shrink its height when the content label is hidden?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a view with two Labels contain in a view as below. They are all constraint 8' from it's side to it's parent view (in grey color). The size of the view basically wrap around the 2 Labels. (like `wrap_content` in Android)

[image]

When both of them coexist, it should display as

[image]

Sometime one of them would exist, and I want the container view to shrink as below

[image]

or

[image]

Notice the size of the container view should shrink to just wrap the contain.

*(Note: I'm an Android Developer, and starting to learn some iOS work. The above could be easily achieve in Android by hiding one of the Label, the container view would then shrink accordingly, as per show above desired result.)*

However, when I do the hide as below

```
labelTwo.isHidden = true
```

It shows as

[image]

And when I do

```
labelOne.isHidden = true
```

It shows as below

[image]

I ask around, seems like I have to manually code in swift set the height = 0 of the hidden Label and remove the relevant constraint programmatically. I find this seems too complicated for what I think should be simple. So asking around to see if there's a simple way to achieve this (e.g. can we use padding instead of constraint, like in Android?, is there a `GONE` feature as in Android's view?)

Is there a way to easily achieve what I want?

Comment: rather than using this approach, use UIStackView, it would automatically take care of resizing.

Comment: Layout constraints will manage automatically if label have no text. No need to hide any particular label.

Comment: Use UIStackView for both the labels, it will manage size of your parent view

Comment: Layout is from the top down, not from the bottom up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two easy ways to do this.

1) Use UIStackView

2) Use height constraint

```
let heightConstraint = secondLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
```

later disable the height constraint when you want to show the view

```
heightConstraint.isActive = false
```

Comment: Between the Labels, I want a space of 8' between them. When I put in UIStackView, I can't get to have the 8'. Any advice how to achieve that?

Comment: UIStackView has a parameter called `spacing` to deal with this. set `labelStackView.spacing = 8`. You can do this in Storyboard itself.

Comment: I achieve what I want using `UIStackView`. The 2 labels is placed within `UIStackView`. However, I don't understand your `Use height constraint`... I use `isHidden=true` already achieve what I need. What do you mean when stating `heightConstraint.isActive = false`?

Comment: Thats an alternative option.. dont use that if you use stackview

Comment: Thanks @CelineBoss. I accepted your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an @IBOutlet on the height constraints and use that variable.

`@IBOutlet weak var someConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!`